# Fragment shuts down after onActivityResult method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

i call `startActivityForResult()` in my Fragment to load image. It handles it the same fragment with `onActivityResult()`. At the end of this method execution Fragment is still on screen, and the next method i can think about is onBackStackChanged where this fragment is actually removed. Can you help me track this bug, for exapmle there is method which is called after `onActivityResult()` and i can set a breakpoint there?

P.S. I've created a new project and copy/pasted this part in it and it worked...
If you need any further explanation or code, please ask

Answer (score 1):

Well, i don't think this is going to help someone, but anyway..
In my activity's superclass' onStart method i've been clearing BackStack completely, so the Fragment was destroyed.